# Adobe AIR for Android - How to use APK expansion files in air app?

Tags: android, air, apk, apk-expansion-files

I have created an AIR app for Android which I am about to submit to Google Play. Total file size of my APK is around 250 MB since I have embedded a lot of video content which is required for the app to run. I cannot download videos from the server as our client does not want users to wait after clicking on each of the video. 
I just found out that maximum APK file size allowed by the Google play store is 50 MB beyond which you will have to use something called APK expansion files. I have never used these in AIR apps before and I searched through a lot of forums but could not find any answer to this problem.

I am stuck just because of this APK size limit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks